# How to create related models within a form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

Newbie question here.

I have two models which are related to each other:

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  attr_accessible :source_item_id, :target_item_id
  belongs_to :target_item, :class_name => "Item"
  belongs_to :source_item, :class_name => "Item"
  belongs_to :user
  ...
end
```

and:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  attr_accessible :address
  ...
end
```

Now, within my form, I already know the source_item_id.  I want to be able to enter an address into the form, and create both a target_item, and the associated Relationship.

```
<%= form_for @new_relationship do |f| %>

    <% @new_relationship.source_item_id = @current_item.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :source_item_id %>       

    <%= f.submit "New Relationship" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You generally do the relationship in the controller and let the form just collect the data. If you are asking how to have a form with two models, check out this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231608/rails-user-input-for-multiple-models-on-a-single-form-how). I hope I understood your question right !!!