# form_for : how to bring 2 variables into view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How can i bring 2 variables into the view. I am newbie in Ruby on rails.

What will the sytax to bring 2 or more values into a view.

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
```

EDIT :

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
prohibited this user from being saved: </h2>
<u1>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
</u1>
</div>
<% end %>
<%= debug @user %>
<div class = "field">
<%= f.label :email %><br/>
<%= f.text_field :email %>
</div>
```

Let's say that in the above code I want to print values from 2 objects and also submit them. How can I do that ?

Comment: What do you mean by "bring 2 or more values into a view"? Do you mean that you want the form to post to more objects than just `@user`, or that you just need to print vars in your view?

Comment: see the updates in the question.

Comment: You can load other objects in the controller action into other instance variables, similar to how @user is setup. If you're talking about loading two models into one form, then that's a complicated setup. I think some added specifics on how you want to use the values might help us answer.

Comment: I am talking about loading 2 model into one form

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231608/rails-user-input-for-multiple-models-on-a-single-form-how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your above comment "I am talking about loading 2 model into one form" I think you need to use two model in one form so rails cast produce good episode on using nested model for form .

You can use  **accepts_nested_attributes_for** for eg. for survey is one model and question is another model you can use question as  nested_attributes  in survey and same you can use answers model in survey model in same form.

For more you can read following link.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast

I hope this will help you.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you need to use 2 variables, I think it would be better to use two separate forms because they are unrelated. If two variables have relations to each other, you should use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and `fields_for` to do work.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for