# Handling a belongs_to in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Editx2:  The short short version:  I think I found my answer:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for

Under heading One-To-One , I think this is what i want?
If so I will just close this out.

EDIT: I found this here:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?autoplay=true

This is close to what I want, but it has many things under the survey (in my case a group) and while I will have many addresses for a group this is in a different area (as locations), but in the main form when the group is created I have ONE address that is the billing address for a group.  So I am not sure how to have like the form look all nice and update the @group.billing_address as described below.

I have a model called Group, in it it has a billing address.  This billing address is of type 'Address'.   In the group model it looks like

```
belongs_to  :billing_address, class_name: 'Address', foreign_key: 'billing_address_id'
```

In my group_test.rb file I can test this functionality very easily:

```
 test 'can add a billing address to a group' do
    group = Group.new
    group.group_name = 'Group test with provider'

    adr = Address.new
    adr.city = 'Las Cruces'
    adr.state = 'New Mexico'
    adr.zip = '88012'
    adr.address_line_one = '382 Dark side of moon'
    adr.address_line_two = ''
    adr.save    

    group.billing_address = adr
    group.save
    assert_not_nil group.billing_address, 'Group did not have any billing address'
  end
```

My question is how would I do the above in a form?  Since my controller group_controller.rb does this on new:

```
def new   
    @group=Group.new       
end
```

It doesn't do anything like:

```
   def new 
    @group=Group.new       
    @group.billing_address.new 
  end
```

To which in my view input tags for the form can't look something like:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <%= f.label "Group Name" %>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>                        
            <td>                        
                <%= f.text_field :group_name , size: 50 %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <%= f.label "Billing Address City" %>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>                        
            <td>                        
                <%= f.text_field :billing_address.city, size: 50 %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

The above does not work.   I didn't expect it to, just trying to demonstrate what I am trying to do.  Is even my thinking right?  or do I have to split the data up like I do sort of more in my test, and do it according to this answer I found on multiple models in a form:

[Rails - User Input for Multiple models on a single form - How](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231608/rails-user-input-for-multiple-models-on-a-single-form-how)

Get the data that way and hook it back together in the controller on the create or update method?

Comment: The Railscast you're referencing is a bit outdated, try this [revised episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised). You might be looking for [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for). Here's a [blog post](https://currentricity.wordpress.com/2011/09/04/the-definitive-guide-to-accepts_nested_attributes_for-a-model-in-rails-3/) regarding the implementation in the model and the form.

Comment: yah I also found the fields_for, the documentation trips me up though cause in it they have def address method in what looks like the model, and I am confused as to why.

Comment: You're second edit shows you're on the right track!

Comment: That's an implementation when you don't have an ActiveRecord model at hand, which you do have. The `def address` there just an attribute reader. Look a bit further down for the ActiveRecord version, which is just a few lines.

Comment: man okay thanks.  I am learning so much stuff I never thought I would learn.  I implemented that fields_for with the accepts_nested_attributes_for all from that definitive blog.  Didn't click save yet as the rest of my form isn't built and it will bomb  but this sounds like I am close.  Was my biggest worry in the application.  My only other is forms/views to connect join data :) that will be another stack over flow question :D  Thanks @ThomasKlemm !

Comment: You were super helpful on this, I had a next question on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32705321/using-fields-for-with-accepts-nested-attributes-for-when-show-edit-is-null-on-ne/32705624#32705624  got it claiming it saves but i don't see the extra data... I am guessing its my strong parameters.