# using fields_for with accepts_nested_attributes_for when show/edit is null on nested obj

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

EDIT:  So i can enter the form and click submit, and on the `show.html.erb` I get this error here:

`undefined method 'address_line_one' for nil:NilClass`

On this line here does it mean there is no mailing_address?

```
 <%= @group.mailing_address.address_line_one %>
```

Even though my fields_for below got that information and should of saved it on the submit...but I think my strong parmeters def down below is preventing that mailing_address from being saved.  If you look at my model you can see how mailing_address is used (also the new action in my controller)

Original post:

Using this blog to do nested forms:

https://currentricity.wordpress.com/2011/09/04/the-definitive-guide-to-accepts_nested_attributes_for-a-model-in-rails-3/

It works pretty well, or seems too.  The new action renders fine and I can input information when I click submit it says it is saved and shows me the show action

But the @group.mailing_address in the show does not seem to exists (Which means clicking edit here also does show nothing in field_for also)

I am guessing it has to do with my `def group_params` though not sure what I am doing wrong.

group Show rb snippet:

```
<p>
  <strong>Group tin:</strong>
  <%= @group.tin %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Group Address:</strong>
  <%= @group.mailing_address.address_line_one %> <!-- dies here nil class -->
  <%= @group.mailing_address.address_line_two %> <br />
  <%= @group.mailing_address.city%>, <%= @group.mailing_address.state %> <%= @group.mailing_address.zip %>
</p>
```

Group model:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to  :mailing_address, class_name: 'Address', foreign_key: 'mailing_address_id'
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :mailing_address

end
```

Group controller:

```
 def show
    #@group = Group.find(params[:id])
 end

 def new
    #is this right?
    @group=Group.new       
    @group.build_mailing_address

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # new.html.erb
        format.json { render json: ghouse }
     end
  end

  def create
    @group = Group.new(group_params)

    respond_to do |format|
        if @group.save
            format.html { redirect_to @group, notice: 'Group was successfully created.'}
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @group }
        else
            format.hmtl { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @group.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
  end
```

And the really important part:

```
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def group_params
  params.require(:group).permit(:group_name, :group_contact, :tin, :npi, :notes, :mailing_address)
end
```

For completeness the _form.html.erb snippet with the fields_for

```
<td>                    
    <%= f.fields_for :mailing_address do |builder| %>
    <div class="field">
       <%= builder.label :address_line_one %><br />
       <%= builder.text_field :address_line_one %><br >
       <%= builder.label :address_line_two %><br />
       <%= builder.text_field :address_line_two %><br />
       <%= builder.label :city %><br />
       <%= builder.text_field :city %> <br />
       <%= builder.label :state %><br />
       <%= builder.text_field :state %> <br />
       <%= builder.label :zip %><br />
       <%= builder.text_field :zip %> <br />
    </div>
   <% end -%>                                                                       
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:mailingaddress` should be `mailing_address_attributes: [address_line_one, address_line_two, ...etc]` in your `group_params` method.

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

You'll also need to add a build_mailing_address if nil to your edit action, for the fields_for to appear appropriately on edit:

```
@group.build_mailing_address if @group.mailing_address.nil?
```

Comment: So in my group_controller the edit action is empty, add that in there?  Also I got an error and realized I didn't fully read the definitive guide link cause I had forgotten in the new action a respond_to do without that it blew up when trying to save the new record what is that doing?  Finally, how come in the show action (regardless of the edit) that data does not exist?  I get an error on these lines in my show erb  `<%= @group.mailing_address.address_line_one %>`

Comment: And do I really need a build_mailing_address if that data should exists when editing?  or does build_mailing_address handle this?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you had a edit action because you stated "(Which means clicking edit here also does show nothing in field_for also)". So you are saying you submitted your form with mailing_address attributes, and ended up with no mailing_address?

Comment: @Codejoy I've updated my answer, looks like you have a typo in group_params, see above.

Comment: Thank you for the response I had actually updated the strong params in my controller and I updated my question with the error I am getting...

Comment: It's been a while, I believe the params key for those attributes would be `:mailing_address_attributes`, not just `:mailing_address`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: My group_params method now has `params.require(:group).permit(:group_name, :group_contact, :tin, :npi, :notes, :mailing_address_attributes)` but same error I get.

Comment: I forgot with strong params and nested attributes you have to declare all of them:

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: @Codejoy in the meantime just to confirm that strong params is the issue, make them like this `params.require(:group).permit!` to allow all.

Comment: man I just did a clap.  That .permit! did it.  I am guessing I wouldn't want this in production though?  That link you sent by declaring all of them here:   `pets_attributes: [ :name, :category ])` would be in my case:  , `mailling_address_attributes: [ :address_line_one, :address_line_two, :city ])` etc correct?  You made my day thanks!   With this down I can extrapolate what I learned to all my forms with nested attributes !!

Comment: @Codejoy that's correct. the `permit!` allows all keys to pass. What you want to do is analyze the params your form is actually sending, and make sure you accomodate them in the array. And that should do the trick.