# Submitting Data form_for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, erb

Is anyone savvy enough to know how I can take this data being submitted and store it in another models database. For Example :

```
<bottom><div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :event %>
      <%= f.text_field :event %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :code %>
      <%= f.text_field :code %>


      <%= f.submit "Create", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
</bottom>
```

The line where it creates a label for event and a textfield for event is there any possible way I can store what the user types in for that in my Events database that has a name row?

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rails - User Input for Multiple models on a single form - How](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231608/rails-user-input-for-multiple-models-on-a-single-form-how)

Essentially you are able to use `fields_for` to solve your problem, I *think* the following code will work but I haven't tried it:

```
  <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      ....
      <% fields_for @event do |e| %>
          <%= e.label :event %>
          <%= e.text_field :event %>
      <% end %>
      ...
  <% end %>
```

Comment: I am getting an error that says unknown model name? Any reason as to why this is?

Comment: Nevermind in the users new function i didn't define a new Event